# Flutter app error on Firebase AUthentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have shifted my flutter app from Ubuntu to MAC OS . ANd now the phone and google signin authentication is not working. Everytime i am trying it is showing error as "Phone Auth Failed"

> This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed. Is app running on a physical device? ]

this is the error in the console.
I have tried everything. Changing the SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys in firebase console also. and changing the google-services json file. But still the error persists and authentication failed.

Comment: how did you transfer your files? You shouldn't transfer your config files from ubuntu to mac os.

Comment: i had transferred the zip file alongwith pubspec and all. And then import the project using import a gradle project in android studio

Comment: i'm not sure how to do it with android studio but what I did was to use github and set the .gitignore to ignore transferring certain files.

Comment: so shall i try transferring the file again using github? and then try running the project

Comment: yeah its worth a try. don't forget to set .gitignore I think there are articles or docs online on how to transfer your flutter prpject using github

Comment: i have tried the same still getting the same error